# Mod_rewrite with any utf8 character

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, utf-8

I need to use links in this format:
http://site.com/index
(or /index-blahblah or /index1 or /index1-blahblah )

where blahblah can contain any UTF 8 character

I wrote the rule below but it doesn't work....please help!

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
RewriteRule ^/?(index|index1)-?(.*)$ main.php?page=$1&keyword=$2 [NC,B,L]
```

It does work if I put a range ...but not with '.'

```
RewriteRule ^/?(index|index1)-*([A-Z]*)$ main.php?page=$1&keyword=$2 [NC,B,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

## domain.com/category-name/ to domain.com/categories.php?name=category-name

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ categories.php?name=$1 [L]

I think this example might help.

Comment: this example doesn't achieve what I want to achieve